# OpenLayers: Error message 404 (Not Found)

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, javascript

I've created a map using openlayers contains osm, google layers and some vector features, On loading it shows two errors like:  **GET http://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/1.png 404 (Not Found)**. How to prevent this , I've googled it, and i can't understand what is the exact problem and how to solve this please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant prevent this. it says that the server you have used for openstreetmap dont have image at this url.

but you can use this code for image loading error:

```
OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError = function(){
           this.src='http://www.openlayers.org/api/img/blank.gif';
};
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Shows a new error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Comment: check your all paths whether they are valid or invalid.

Comment: I've not used paths to create map only added two scripts: <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.3"></script> 
   
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>

Comment: @Aragon, onImageLoadError has been deprecated, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the second tile (in the y direction) in zoom level 0. It only has one tile at that level (at http://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png).

Something is wrong with your code, or the js you are importing.

Answer (score 1):

### OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadError no longer exists

To replace a tile that couldn't be loaded with a static image, create a css selector for the `.olImageLoadError` class (e.g. a `background-image`):

```
.olImageLoadError {
    background: url(./images/missing-tile.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

For more complex tile loading error handling, register a listener to the layer's `tileerror` event.

Corresponding issues/pull requests:

- https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/283

`onImageLoadError` was removed by [this](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/91cd42bfe6ad737450f18d7488905c233ad9814d#L2L329) commit.